# How To Use Form_For to Update a Hash Attribute in the Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, form-for

A quick warning: I am pretty new to Rails, and my knowledge is somewhat cookie-cutter-esque. I know how to do certain things, but I lack that vital understanding of why they always work.

I currently have a User model that has in it a bunch of information, like address, email, etc. In addition, it also has a hash called visible. The keys in that hash are each of the pieces of information, and the value is either true or false for whether the user wishes that information to be publicly visible. While I'm not sure if this is the best way to go, I can't think of any other way other than making a whole ton of boolean variables for each bit of information. Finally, I serialize :visible for storage in the database

What I would like is in my edit view to have a checkbox beside each field of info that represents the visible attribute.  After reading tons of other posts related to this topic and trying numerous variations of code, I always end up with some kind of an error. The code that looks most intuitively correct to me is as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :id => "form-info-personal") do |f| %>
...
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.check_box :visible[:name] %>
```

But I get an error message saying that a Symbol cannot be parsed into an integer. I'm not sure where this parse is even trying to happen, unless its viewing :visible as an array and trying to use :name as an index.

I apologize in advance if this question is trivial/seemingly nonsensical/lacking vital information/etc. Any tips, suggestions, links, or what have you would be very appreciated, even if they're along the lines of "you're doing this fundamentally wrong, go back and do it this way".

-Nick

Comment: Stay away from the serialization. It's the first problem you got, but you will have more problems because of serialization. Adding specific columns is not wrong at all.

Comment: @wanghq: There's nothing wrong with serialization (if you cook it right).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 3.2 introduces a [nice addition to ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#active-record), which allows you to store arbitrary settings in a single field.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ]
end

u = User.new(color: 'black', homepage: '37signals.com')
u.color                          # Accessor stored attribute
u.settings[:country] = 'Denmark' # Any attribute, even if not specified with an accessor
```

So, your code could look like this:

```
# model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :name_visible, :email_visible ]

end

# view
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.check_box :name_visible %>
```

Comment: Do you think its worth updating my app from 3.1 to 3.2 for this addition? As this is my first Rails app, I'm unaware as to how difficult it would be to "upgrade". Unless I am mistaken, Rails does not ensure backwards-compatibility, so there's always the change that in my attempt to make life easier in one way, I find myself with a slew of new problems.

Comment: 3.1 to 3.2 upgrade is [absolutely painless](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#upgrading-to-rails-3-2). You just have to change some gem versions in Gemfile. No reason not to upgrade.

Comment: Okay, so the upgrade was painless and the model updated. I can edit it in the console and it works quite nicely. Only problem is the form doesn't appear to be updating those fields. I have no idea why this is; the form still updates all the other fields, but changing the checkbox to true still results in the :settings field being {}. Any ideas?
Update: Manually setting the value of a field like name_visible in the console results in a change in the way the checkbox looks on form load, but changing the value of the checkbox doesn't change the value in the database.

Comment: Aha! Each individual field needs to be attr_accesible, not just the general field (:settings). It's all working :)

Comment: @ngmiceli: Cool! I was just composing a test example for you :)